# Calculate MD5 hash from bufferd stream (BinaryReader and using buffer)

Tags: c#, buffer, md5, binaryreader

I need to calculate a MD5 hash from a bufferd stream (BinaryReader).
I can calculate the MD5 hash for the buffer (bytes), but how to calculate the MD5 hash for the complete stream ?
Can't load whole data into memory !

Comment: Unless you require your code to be non-blocking, you could just use [`HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19.aspx) method overload.

Comment: I'll give give them both a try